# Go through each record in mongoose and see how times a specific column matches items in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

sorry in advanced I'm new to mongo. I have somewhat of a complex aggregation query that needs to be written. I am needing to go through each record and see how many items from an array that it has on a specific column. E.g.

Imagine I have an array of tags that I want to filter by:

```
const tags = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to figure out how many items from the tags variable that each record contains on a `tags` column. `So if a record contains [1, 2, 3, ...] then the score should be 3`, if it contains `[1, 2, ...] the score should be 2`, etc. It does not need to be exact match, instead I'm simply wanting to know how many `tags` a record contains from the passed array above. If a record doesn't have any of the tags, I would prefer it to get filtered out but it's not required.

My schema looks like:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
    tags: {
        type: Array,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});
```

My expected result would be an array of items with the score of how many tags it matched:

```
[
  {
    name: "$name",
    description: "$description",
    tags: "$tags"
    score: { $sum: 1 }

  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the size of the array and not the value of the last tag.
You can use `$size` it counts and returns the total number of items in an array. [Take a look at mongodb $size documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  setIntersection expression so you can have some thing like `score: {$size:{$setIntersection:["$tags", tags]}}`
Where the second tags is the one that you want to find. This should do the trick. The setIntersection will return in array with items that are found in both arrays after which you can simply return the size of the array